# How we can decreases the loading time of WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress

I have developed wordpress website but after hitting it is taking so much time for loading , this is my website link http://www.dahotreanddahotre.com/.

Tell me any plugin or manual setting such that i can decreases the loading time of my website?

Comment: First of all resolve your console error i found some jquery bug there.

Comment: Try out pantheon.io - most optimized WP platform I've found. It's containerized, based on Docker or similar.

Comment: @staypuftman hosting isn't the only thing that makes a website fast.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do:

## Cache

Use a cache system: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/

This will let you serve your fixed pages a lot faster to the user.

## Minify

Use some minifier: https://wordpress.org/plugins/fast-velocity-minify/

This will make included javascript, css files smaller and thus they will take less time to load

## Identify image needs

Looking at the network dev-tools a lot of the loading time (**4 seconds +**) comes from huge images:

[image: 4 seconds to load images]

1st image (1.47MB): http://www.dahotreanddahotre.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/We-intend-to-be-your-financial-lifeline.jpg

2nd image (1.64MB): http://www.dahotreanddahotre.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/We-are-startup-friendly.jpg

Use a Image compressor before uploading them and don't upload images that are bigger than you need.

For example image2 is: **4,300px × 2,862px** this could be reduced and compressed.

By decreasing it's size to: **2,150px x 1,431px** and compressing it, it becomes only: **350kb**

## Checking unreachable resources

Still looking at the dev tool I could see some fonts which where giving a 404 error (**almost 2 seconds loading**).

[image: unreachable resources]

This means the font is unreachable but the browser still spends time to try to load it.

Make sure all resources are reachable and unused one are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use good hosting
2. Avoid bunch of plugins
3. Get a custom wordpress theme starting from scratch
4. Avoid page builders
5. Optimize images used in website

Comment: I would disagreee with the theme and page builder point. I use on a few clients websites some page builders and some theme found online and the websites load pretty quick

Comment: I did plenty of designs in my past which was not possible in any builder, only gave my opinion, that's it!